# Optimal way to synchronize sequential part of work among parallel threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a large collection of jobs (with identifier `1` to `n`) to be run in a thread pool. Each worker thread takes one piece of job at a time, until all are done. Each job contains a parallel section that is independent of each other, followed by a sequential part that must be run one by one, i.e. job `1`, `2`, `3`, ... `n`.

**Illustration:**

```
worker thread               worker thread  worker thread
 ↓                           ↓              ↓
||| \                       |||            |||
|||  \                      |||            |||
|||   Parallel work         |||            |||
|||  /                      |||            | |
||| /                       |||            | |
 ↓                           ↓    .....     ↓ (Proceed only after job k-1 has finished)
|-| \                       |-|            | |
|-|  Sequential work --->   |-|            | |
|-| /                       | |            | |
                                           
---                         ---            ---
job 1                       job 2          job k
```

Typically, the parallel part takes much more time than the sequential part. Both are mostly CPU-bound computations. The number of workers in the thread pool is chosen according to the number of logical CPU cores.

I'm looking for an optimal way to synchronize the worker threads.

**Current method**

I'm using a global counter to keep the sequential work in correct order. The code is something like below:

```cpp
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cond;
unsigned current_id = 1;
for (unsigned i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    my_thread_pool.enqueueJob(
    [&, i] {
        //
        // do parallel work for job i
        //
        {
            std::unique_lock lk(mtx);
            cond.wait(lk, [&]{ return i == current_id; });
            //
            // do sequential work for job i
            //
            ++current_id;
        }
        cond.notify_all();
    }
    );
}
```

This seems to work correctly so far, however I wonder if it's the canonical way of solving such problems, since `notify_all()` was used to wake up all waiting threads, while only one of them really needs to wake up.

Comment: If you can use the standard execution policies, I'd give those a try. The internal thread pool usually does a very good job for these kinds of things.